# javascript inside php error ReferenceError: img is not defined

Tags: php, javascript

photos[] is an array of photos names then,

```
foreach($photos as $key=>$value)
{
    @$blocks .= '<div><img src="'.$value.'" onload="img=this"><img src="remove.png" onclick=remove_image(img)></div>';
}
```

so when clicking on the remove icon for the first photo it works just fine, but the others shows this error:

`ReferenceError: img is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you LukeGT, your answer is right, but I found it better to use jquery to handle it,

```
onclick="remove_image($(this).prev())"
```

or

```
onclick="remove_image($(this).parent())"
```

to remove the whole div.

Answer (score 3):

The `img` variable is being stored globally, which means that it's getting overwritten each time a new image loads.  You should instead assign the images unique ID's, and have their remove buttons remove the image by ID.  For example:

```
foreach($photos as $key=>$value)
{
    @$blocks .= '<div><img src="'.$value.'" id="img'.$key.'"><img src="remove.png" onclick=remove_image(document.getElementById("img'.$key.'"))></div>';
}
```

(I'm not super familiar with PHP, so sorry if I made a syntax error somewhere)

Comment: Use $key and drop $a. $key will be the index of the photo in the array, thus unique.

Answer (score 0):

You should refresh page when clicked delete button.